# Creating a column in Dataframe if values exist in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a number of columns. There are 3 columns that contain rows that are either blank or, if the row corresponds to the column variable, have a random number/letter string. I would like to take this data and create another column that has a string with the name of the variable for each row.

For example:

```
    raw_data['A']
Out[192]: 
0        00Q2400000GUxMjEAL
1        00Q2400000G5QDzEAN
2                       NaN
3                       NaN
4                       NaN
5                       NaN
```

So far I have tried writing a function to apply but it only returns 'xyz' for every row.

```
def type(row):
    if row['A'] is not None:
        return 'xyz'
    elif row['B'] is not None:
        return 'acb'
    else:
        return 'efg'

raw_data['TUV'] = raw_data.apply(lambda row: type(row), axis = 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens is both column values have `NaN` or both have a string/number value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pd.notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas.notnull):

```
def type(row):

    if pd.notnull(row['A']):
        return 'xyz'
    elif pd.notnull(row['B']):
        return 'acb'
    else:
        return 'efg'

df['TUV'] = df.apply(lambda row: type(row), axis = 1)
```

Edit better to use pd.notnull

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Manuel! For some reason, every single row in `df['TUV']` is coming out as 'xyz'. Could there be something wrong with my lambda function? It seems like it's applying the result for the comparison in the first row to the entire Series.

Comment: Your lamba function works perfectly, your function type(row) not, you must change "row['A'] is not None" to "pd.notnull(row['A'])", as my answer indicates.

Comment: Sorry, I had changed to pd.notnull() but didn't include 'row' inside the function which is why it wasn't iterating through. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With bigger datasets, `apply` can be slow.
Even with just 10,000 rows, you can get about a **25x speedup** on this task with simple indexing operations.

Here's some example data:

```
N = 10000
data = {"A": np.random.choice([1, None], size=N),
        "B": np.random.choice([1, None], size=N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
      A     B
0     1     1
1  None     1
2     1     1
3     1     1
4  None  None
```

Using basic assignment and indexing:

```
%%timeit

df["TUV"] = "efg"
df.loc[df.A.notnull(), "TUV"] = "xyz"
df.loc[df.B.notnull(), "TUV"] = "acb"
# 6.15 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using `apply`:

```
%%timeit

def type(row):

    if pd.notnull(row['A']):
        return 'xyz'
    elif pd.notnull(row['B']):
        return 'acb'
    else:
        return 'efg'

df['TUV2'] = df.apply(lambda row: type(row), axis = 1)
# 152 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

df.TUV.equals(df.TUV2) # True
```

Comment: Very fast solution, but I believe that the return of values is not the same as in the function, is the order of df.loc[df.B.notnull(), "TUV"] = "acb" and 
df.loc[df.A.notnull(), "TUV"] = "xyz" correct?